# Unable to print Outlook tasks

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007, printing, tasks

I'm unable to print (or print preview) Outlook tasks. All other areas of Outlook print successfully (email, calendar, etc.).

Here are some details about my system:

1) Windows 7 
2) Outlook 2007
3) 64 bit
4) All latest MS updates are installed

Any feedback on why this might be happening or how to correct it would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you,

Leo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the cause of this, but here are the steps I would take to try and fix it. Many of which you may have already done!

1. Restart outlook
2. Restart Windows
3. Try using a different printer as the default printer
4. Reinstall the printer drivers
5. Repair the installation of Outlook
6. Remove Office completely and reinstall
7. Scream in frustration because computers should make our lives easier not harder!

Comment: Sam, your response inspired me to update the driver. But that didn't work. HOWEVER... although... on a fluke, I selected to print "tasks" rather than the "to-do" list and it now prints. I'm not sure why but I'll take it for now.

Thanks for your response!

Answer (score 1):

### Windows 10 Office 365 Solution

You have a corrupted Outlook print file.  I spent much time reading a bunch of dead end suggestions.  The five simple steps below solved my issue.

1. Close Outlook
2. Navigate to the following directory **%userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Outlook**.
3. You should see a file in this directory named **OutlPrnt**.
4. Add *.old* as a file extension to the file -> *OutlPrnt.old*.
5. Restart Outlook (you may need to reboot - I didn't).

In my case Outlook did not create a new OutlPrnt file.  It appears it just no longer needs the reference to that file.

Answer (score 0):

I could not print either. I had my task list in detailed list view.

I then switched it to simple lists view and was able to print.

After that, i switched it to active tasks view and was able to print again.

Finally, I switched it back to detailed view and it was done, I was able to print in the view that I use (detailed list).